# Is it possible to use 2 different keyboards without having to switch the layout manually?

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, keybindings

I have multiple keyboard attached to one of my macs. One is more of the gamer type the other is the usual bluetooth keyboard.

One is French (Windows AZERTY) the other one is US (Mac QWERTY).

Is it possible to use both without having to switch the layout manually every time we switch from one to the other in OS X?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, but you might have a look at the Karabiner app, which I've heard has ways of distinguishing hardware keyboards.

Manual switching is in any case very fast using the Command plus space shortcut.